# Non-deterministic Rails association default order?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following models

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, -> { order(rank: :asc)}
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Rails seems to ignore the default ordering when building queries with `eager_load` but includes them when using `preload`...

```
Company.preload(:employees)
Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies"
Employee Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."company_id" = 1 ORDER BY "employees"."rank" ASC
=> [#<Company:0x00007f808c9e73c0 id: 1, name: "Acme Co">]
```

^^^ Note the 'correct' application of `ORDER BY employees.rank ASC`

```
Company.eager_load(:employees)
SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT "companies"."id" AS t0_r0, "companies"."name" AS t0_r1, "employees"."id" AS t1_r0, "employees"."name" AS t1_r1, "employees"."rank" AS t1_r2, "employees"."company_id" AS t1_r3 FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "employees" ON "employees"."company_id" = "companies"."id"
```

^^^ Note the lack of any kind of employee ordering

(I guess that makes sense when you think about it. What if you have multiple associations being joined in, all with their own default ordering...how would that even work. I also recognize relying on a default sort order in the association is a bit contrived and not best practice with this example, but there are many scenarios where I could see that being a valid approach.)

The problem seems to arise when you do something like `Company.includes(:employees).first.employees.first.award_bonus` assuming those employees are ordered by rank. That will work if Rails decides to use `preload` when including employees, but will not necessarily work if Rails decides to use `eager_load` (employees would be ordered by however the DB implements it's default sorting)

Why does Rails even allow specifying an order in an association's default scope? It would almost feel better if an exception was thrown.

Comment: To be very honest, even I feel the same way. Associations should have been kept simple. Specifying the order, or passing a lambda modified an entire association in an unprecedented way. If at all such modifications were needed, the `scopes` were good enough; piling up the same on the association seems completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why does Rails even allow specifying an order in an association's default scope?

Because Rails likes to [provide sharp knives](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#provide-sharp-knives).

> The knives provided by the framework are not nearly as sharp as those offered with the language, but some are still plenty keen to cut. We will make no apologies for offering such tools as part of the kit. In fact, we should celebrate having enough faith in the aspirations of our fellow programmers to dare trust them.

Maybe more to your point though, this appears to be a bug that has been known about forever and has never gotten fixed, see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6769

Comment: Thanks for the link!....was looking for a better discussion about this. In both the production bug that I ran into as well as my included example, I think it's clear relying on the association's default sort order probably isn't the best idea even if it did work as I expected, so maybe I deserve to be cut :). That being said I don't mind sharp knives, as long as they're consistently sharp. If includes() is going to abstract away the decision of preload() versus eager_load() it probably should ensure the same results regardless.